# Eclipse: how to create a standalone server from an Eclipse configuration

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse noob and web dev noob here. I have inherited an eclipse project which has a (Tomcat) server that I can start/stop.

How can I make this a "standalone" server, which does not require me to start eclipse and click run?

Comment: Download Tomcat and run it there?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn how to do that is my question

Comment: Depends on the OS. On linux, use your package manager to install tomcat. It should come with the relevant init scripts, you you can start it like any other deamon. For windows, [download tomcat from it's website](http://tomcat.apache.org/), it comes with an installer, which again installs tomcat as a windows service. Guiding you through the installation / administration of tomcat is outside the scope of this site, so I have to refer to the tomcat documentation.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn -- thanks for helping a newbie. I know how to install Tomcat, what I meant is, how to export the server from Eclipse so that I can run it. In the server settings I don't find any paths to the produced artefact(s)

Comment: Export your project as .war, install it using the tomcat manager. (Or drop it into some folder, not sure which one).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn thanks for getting me started!